# Stata: Suppress label of categorical variable in pie chart if under a certain percentage

Tags: graph, stata, categorical-data

Is there a way to suppress labeling of variables in a pie chart if they are under a specified percentage? Perhaps, when specifying plabel() in the graph pie options, there is syntax to force Stata to not label a variable in the pie chart if its share is under 10%? While I can adjust the font size of the pie chart labels in plabel(), there are still several labels that overlap due to their variables' small share. I know that I can specify how to label individual slices of the pie chart, but I am producing a large number of graphics and would prefer to not relabel individual slices.

Comment: Not the answer you seek, perhaps, but the "problem" you are addressing arguably arises because a pie chart can be a poor choice for such data. A bar or dot chart can readably show both small fractions and their category labels.

Comment: The idea that you want to show a category but not label it is interesting. In addition to @Dimitriy's helpful answer, it would be possible to program aggregation of small categories into an "other" category. Sorry, but I am not volunteering code, as I think using other graphs a better answer and it's not a problem that interests me.

Answer (score 2):

There's no official way to do this as far as I know. Here's one clunky way that relies on re-ordering the categories from largest to smallest from 12 o'clock going clockwise. When your variable is ordered, this behavior will be undesirable, but then I would prefer a histogram anyway:

```
sysuse auto, clear

foreach var of varlist rep78 mpg turn {
  qui count if !missing(`var')
  bys `var': gen frac = _N/r(N)
  gsort -frac
  levelsof `var' if frac>.10

  local wc: word count `r(levels)'
  local plabel ""

  forvalues i=1/`wc' {
    local plabel "`plabel' plabel(`i' name)"
  }

  graph pie, over(`var') `plabel' sort descending

  drop frac 
}
```

What makes all the re-sorting necessary is that Stata labels pie slices from 1 to k starting at 12 o'clock and there's no ability to attach labels to underlying numeric values.

Comment: @SKA No need to thank me. If you found the answer useful, please select it as the answer on the left.